# Unable to invoke a function using onClick event handler in React JS JSX fie

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-engine

Hi I have been trying to invoke a function using onClick button event handler to submit a form in my .jsx file. However, this doesn't seem to be happening. Below are the codes I am using to achieve the same.

Layout.jsx (this has all the logic of functions)

```
import React from 'react';
//import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
//import Success from "./components/success.jsx";   
//import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; 

class Layout extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            showComments: false,
            comments:[{id:1, author:"sourav", body:"That's Awsome"}]
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        console.log(this.state.comments)  
    }

    getComments(){
        return this.state.comments.map((comment) => {
            var fullComment = [comment.author, comment.body].join(" ");
            console.log("fullComment", fullComment);
            return fullComment;
            }
        )
    }

    addComment(author, body){
        console.log("inside addComment")
        const commentMessage = {
            id: this.state.comments.length + 1,
            author,
            id
        }
        this.setState({comments:this.state.comments.concat([commentMessage])});
    }

    submitHandler(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        let author = this.author;
        let body = this.body;
        console.log("author is", author);
        addComment(author.value, body.value)
    }



    render() {
        return (
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>JSX</title>
                    <link rel = "stylesheet" src = "../../css/app.less"/>
                </head>

                <body>
                    <h1>Welcome to Comment form</h1>
                    <div id = "maincontent">

                        <form onSubmit = {this.submitHandler.bind(this)}>
                            Author : <br/>
                            <input placeholder = "Name" ref = {(input) => this.author = input}/><br/><br/>
                            Your Comment:<br/>
                            <textarea placeholder = "Enter comments" ref = {(textarea) => this.body = textarea}></textarea><br/><br/>
                            <input type = "submit" placeholder = "Add Comment"/>
                        </form>
                        <p>{this.getComments.bind(this)}</p>
                    </div>

                </body>

            </html>
            );
    }
}



Layout.propTypes = {

}

Layout.defaultProps = {

}

/*class CommentClass extends React.Component{



    render(){

    }
}*/

//ReactDOM.render(<Layout/>, document.getElementById("para"));
export default Layout;
```

app.jsx

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import Layout from './layout.jsx';
import {Router, RouteHandler} from 'react-router';

/*export default React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <Layout {...this.props}>
                <Router.RouteHandler {...this.props} />
            </Layout>
        );
    }
});*/

class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <Layout {...this.props}>
                <Router.RouteHandler {...this.props} />
            </Layout>
            )
    }
}

export default App;
```

react.jsx

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import { Route,createRoutes } from 'react-router';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Layout from '../public/views/layout.jsx';
import App from '../public/views/app.jsx'

const routes = createRoutes(
    <Route path='/' component={App}>
        <Route path="/signin" component={Layout}></Route>
    </Route>
);

/*let routes = (
    <Route path='/' component={App}>
        <Route path="/signin" name = "layout" component={Layout}></Route>
    </Route>
    )*/

export default routes;

//ReactDOM.render(<Route path = '/signin' component = {Layout}></Route>)
```

Could you please help me out of this ? Please let me know if any other information is required.

Answer (score 1):

In your `submitHandler` function, change

`addComment(author.value, body.value)`

to

`this.addComment(author.value, body.value)`

`addComment` is a attached to `Layout.prototype`, so you must access it on the instance of `<Layout />`.

Comment: Hi, I have already tried that. The problem here is submitHander even is not getting invoked..

Comment: Unless you're leaving out even more code, then `submitHandler` _will_ be called once the submit button is invoked.

Comment: Could you please elaborate ? I am unable to understand this point.

Comment: Also, I am getting the below warning when I am starting the server `Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `App`.
[ { id: 1, author: 'sourav', body: 'That\'s Awsome' } ]`

Comment: This would have all been information that you should have included in the actual question.

Comment: Can you help me with this ? @Ray